# Why are these things happening?

Tags: java, button, timer, awt, timertask

[EDIT] Okay thanks to Malte Kölle, the 'c' calculation stops after it is removed. There is still the problem of the 'c' being not on press but I have noticed another problem. The speed variables 'sw' and 'sh' stack if the spawn button is pressed repeatedly and I don't know how to avoid that. I cant set the speed variables equal to zero because its inside an internal class. I have updated the code.

I decided to create a simple button game in java using AWT where there is a button 'b' in the center that spawns another button 'c' that moves on the screen. When 'c' is clicked it is deleted. 'c' moves around fine but I am having two problems.

1. Often clicking 'c' shows the pressed animation but then continues to exist afterward. How would I make it run its actionListener on press rather than on depress?
2. When 'c' is clicked and removed, the calculations for its movement are still running even though it doesn't exist. I have no idea how to fix this.

Extra. After these issues are fixed, the next step is to be able to spawn multiple buttons with the same attributes. If anyone has suggestions for that they would be appreciated, but not necessary.

I have quite a few system outputs to detect problems like these so thats how I knew it was still calculating. This is my first code project so if there are any other ways it could be improved please let me know. 
Thank You!

```
public class Main {

    Frame f = new Frame("Button Game");
    Button b = new Button("Spawn Button");
    Button c = new Button("Click Me!");

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
    int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    int fh = f.getHeight();
    int fw = f.getWidth();
    boolean cExists;

    Main () {
        f.setSize(screenWidth/2,screenHeight/2); //Sets frame size
        f.setLocation(screenWidth/4,screenHeight/4); //Sets frame location
        f.setLayout(null); //Sets layout manager
        f.setVisible(true); //Sets frame to be visible
        System.out.println("Frame height:" + f.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Frame width:" + f.getWidth());
        fh = f.getHeight() + 20;
        fw = f.getWidth();

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosing(e);
                System.out.println("Window closed by window listener");
                f.dispose();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });

        f.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                super.componentResized(e);
                fw = f.getWidth();
                fh = f.getHeight();
                System.out.println("Frame size changed to " + f.getSize());
                b.setBounds(fw/2 - 60,fh/2 - 15, 120, 30);
                System.out.println("Button 'b' re-centered to " + b.getLocation());

                if (fw <= 320 || fh <= 180) {
                    f.setSize(320,180);
                }
            }
        });

        f.add(b);
        b.setBounds(fw/2 - 60,fh/2 - 15, 120, 30);
        System.out.println("Button 'f' spawned at " + b.getLocation());
        b.setVisible(true);

        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int rn1 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(30, fw - 130);
                int rn2 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(50, fh - 60);
                f.add(c);
                cExists = true;
                c.setBounds(rn1, rn2, 100, 30);
                System.out.println("Button 'c' created at " + c.getLocation());

                int sh = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-5, 10);
                int sw = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-5, 10);
                System.out.println("Speed vertical: " + sh);
                System.out.println("Speed horizontal: " + sw);
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                class remindTask extends TimerTask {
                    public void run() {
                        if (cExists) {
                            c.setBounds(c.getX() + sw, c.getY() + sh, 100, 30);
                            System.out.println("Button 'c' moved to " + c.getLocation());
                            if (c.getX() >= fw-130) {
                                c.setBounds(30 + sw, c.getY() + sh, 100, 30);
                            } else if (c.getY() >= fh-60) {
                                c.setBounds(c.getX() + sw, 30 + sh, 100, 30);
                            } else if (c.getX() <= 30) {
                                c.setBounds(fw - 130 + sw, c.getY() + sh, 100, 30);
                            } else if (c.getY() <= 30) {
                                c.setBounds(c.getX() + sw, fh - 15 + sh, 100, 30);
                            }
                        } else {
                            timer.cancel();
                            //sw = 0; cant because it is inside an internal class. Maybe outsource to a method?
                            //sh = 0; Error:(94, 33) java: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final
                        }
                    }
                }
                timer.schedule(new remindTask(), 0, 100);
            }
        });

        c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                f.remove(c);
                cExists = false;
                System.out.println("'cExists' set to false");
                System.out.println("Removed button 'c' at " + c.getLocation());
            }
        });
    }

public static void main(String[] args) { //Calls code
    System.out.println("Code beginning"); //Logs beginning of runtime
    try { //Runs Main through run
        Main f = new Main();
        f.run(args);
    }
    catch (Exception e){ //NOT SURE
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run (String[] args) throws Exception{ //New method to call non-static things
    System.out.println("Frame created");
}
```

Comment: don't try to learn awt, it's like a helpdesk agent learning Windows 1. It's way out of date. Without your actual output, it's pretty hard to see what's going on/wrong

Answer (score 0):

You're trying t check if cExists is True. But to do so you will need two '==' instead of only one.

Line 77:

```
public void run() {
  if (cExists == true) {
     c.setBounds(c.getX() + sw, c.getY() + sh, 100, 30);
```

The cleaner way of checking if a Boolean is true is probably like this:

```
if(cExists){
```

I tried it on my Project and it works for me.

edit:
The difference between one equal sign '=' and two equal signs '==':

One equal sign is an assignment operation. You're using it to assign a value to a variable.

Example:

```
int number = 7
```

Here you are assigning the value 7 to the variable 'number'

Two equal signs is used to check some condition, for example:

```
if(number == 7){
   // do something
}
```

Which is what you are looking for since it means 'if number equals 7'.

Comment: you could add the difference between the two operators in this case

Comment: What I meant was, if ( cExists = true ) is equal to cExists = true; if ( cExists ) :)